# Insert list box items to sql server

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, listbox

I am trying to add items from a list box to a foreign key table in sql server.

Any items in the list box should be added to the database.

Current I am stuck on the loop because it is not collecting the item in the list box.

The items in the list box will not be selected.

Any tips would be great!

```
Dim CommandText As String = "INSERT INTO code (id, Code, specialty) VALUES (@id, @ClientCode, @specialty);"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(CommandText, sqlconninsertDB)

For Each item As ListItem In lstspecialty.Items
                If Items.Count = lstspecialty.Items.Count Then
                    Try
                        With cmd.Parameters
                            .Add(New SqlParameter("@id", ID))
                            .Add(New SqlParameter("@ClientCode", Code))
                            .Add(New SqlParameter("@specialty", item.Value))
                        End With

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Label.Text = "Data Inserted"
                Catch ex As Exception
                     ErrorLabel.Text = "Error Message"
                End Try
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: What is the value of `cmd.CommandText`?

Comment: Please elaborate on your issue. In general, if you are stuck, you need to be calling for a tow truck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim SQL as String = "INSERT INTO YourTable(id, ClientCode, specialty) VALUES (@id, @ClientCode, @specialty)"

Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, Connection)

For Each item As ListItem In lstspecialty.Items
            Try
                    With cmd.Parameters
                        .Add(New SqlParameter("@id", item.ID))
                        .Add(New SqlParameter("@ClientCode", item.Code))
                        .Add(New SqlParameter("@specialty", item.Value))
                    End With
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Catch ex As Exception

                 'Whatever you want'

            End Try            
 Next
```